# How to export objects from within ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ecmascript-6

I am exporting a object as below:

//apiEndpoints.ts

```
import {CONSTANTS} from './constants';

let remote = CONSTANTS.API_ENDPOINT;

export const ENDPOINT = {
  signup: remote + 'auth/signup',
  checkusername: remote + 'auth/checkUsername/${username}' 
};
```

Upon importing this module, ENDPOINT is not imported.

see attached error[image]

Comment: That looks like typescript.

Comment: @evolutionxbox why is that needed?

Comment: @Neal - it's not... I just found this quote from MDN _"Note: This feature is not implemented in any browsers natively at this time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as the Traceur Compiler, Babel or Rollup."_

Comment: Harmony won't get you `import`. It looks like @smv is using Typescript, i think?

Comment: this is ES6 folks .. not typescript.. and yes.. it'e being transpiled. My entire application seems to work fine other than this one particular export.. so if you don't understand what's going on .. dont start marking with negative points

Comment: @SMV, this **is** TypeScript. No doubt about it (.ts extension, @ annotations). Does not matter. To your question, since you get a runtime, not a compilation error, my guess is the dependencies are fine and for some reason the file is not visible to the browser for some reason (not included in the bundle, system.js does not see if, if you use it, or so). Where to search for it depends on your workflow. I would start in the network panel or examine the contents of the bundle.

Comment: Have you tried logging `ENDPOINT` in your `signupData.service.ts`

Comment: _"so if you don't understand what's going on"_ This is a disrespectful insult, but it's funny because it's actually true for you. Most important indicator: You asked the question ^^ Another indicator: ES6  neither has annotations / decorators nor access modifiers nor types. Your screenshot shows the original code. The sidebar on the right, like the console, refers to the code that is actually being executed, the transpiled and packaged one. In other words: You did not post the error yet. The screenshot is only a demonstration of your misunderstanding. `ENDPOINT` **is** imported.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a transpiler. In the actual output code, there is no variable called `ENDPOINT` because the transpiler has renamed it. You are getting an error when you type that in the debugger console because it doesn't exist with that name. You can see in the scope inspector in the sidebar, the name you'd actually have to type is

```
apiEndpoints_1.ENDPOINT
```

where the name of the object is based off of the filename of the module being imported, and the property is the exported key. The renaming is done in this case to make sure that the code behaves properly to take ES6 live import bindings into account.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Ionic v2 project. Ionic v2 uses the typescript transpiler. 
The majority of the features that the transpiler works on are ECMAScript 2015 related.

The error I am referring to is about the module implementation in ECMAScript 2015. To learn more see

```
http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html
```

Hence, in an ideal world, I should be able to export constants, variables, functions and classes. However for some reason when I attempt to export  variables and objects .. it fails.

It does not fail on classes.

@loganfsmyth is right. It is importing the module, but renaming it and hence rendering it unusable.

I had to rethink the implementation and am using a different approach for now until I figure out a solution to this issue.

Thanks all who tried.